# User entity of my domain v2

Tags: php, object-oriented, classes

I would appreciate a thorough review of my updated `User` entity class. It's still an anemic domain model, but behavior (like `upgradeToPremium()`, etc) will be added as I'm developing my application further.

This is the *first* time that I'm commenting my code properly according to the [phpDocumenter](http://www.phpdoc.org/) docs. So some feedback on that would also be highly appreciated.

Any other suggestions are always welcome.

---

**User** class:

```
namespace Model\Domain\User;

use Model\Domain\Entity\Entity;
use Model\Domain\User\Value\Email;
use Model\Domain\User\Value\Token;
use Model\Domain\User\Value\FullName;
use Model\Domain\User\Value\Password;
use Model\Domain\User\Authentication;
use Model\Domain\User\Value\SeriesNumber;
use Model\Domain\User\Value\RegisterDateTime;

/**
 * User entity of the problem domain.
 *
 * @author John Doe <http://google.com>
 */
class User extends Entity
{
    /**
     * @var FullName $fullName A full name value object.
     */
    private $fullName;

    /**
     * @var Email $email An email value object.
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var Password $password A password value object.
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var RegisterDateTime $registerDateTime A register date and time value object.
     */
    private $registerDateTime;

    /**
     * @var array $authentications A list of Authentication child entities.
     */
    private $authentications = [];

    /**
     * Gets the full name value object.
     *
     * @return FullName A FullName instance.
     */
    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->fullName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the FullName instance.
     *
     * @param FullName $fullName A FullName instance.
     *
     * @return self The current User entity.
     */
    public function setFullName(FullName $fullName)
    {
        $this->fullName = $fullName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the email address.
     *
     * @return string An email address.
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the Email instance.
     *
     * @param Email $email An Email instance.
     *
     * @return self The current User entity.
     */
    public function setEmail(Email $email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the password.
     *
     * @return string A password.
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the Password instance.
     *
     * @param Password $password A Password instance.
     *
     * @return self The current User entity.
     */
    public function setPassword(Password $password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the date and time of registering.
     *
     * @return string A date and time of registering.
     */
    public function getRegisterDateTime()
    {
        return (string) $this->registerDateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the RegisterDateTime instance.
     *
     * @param RegisterDateTime $registerDateTime A RegisterDateTime instance.
     *
     * @return self The current User entity.
     */
    public function setRegisterDateTime(RegisterDateTime $registerDateTime)
    {
        $this->registerDateTime = $registerDateTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Assembles an Authentication child entity and adds it to the list.
     *
     * @param integer $seriesNumber     A series number.
     * @param string  $token            A token.
     * @param string  $registerDateTime A date and time of registering.
     *
     * @throws Exception if series number is not unique.
     */
    public function addAuthentication($seriesNumber, $token, $registerDateTime)
    {
        if ($this->findAuthenticationBySeriesNumber($seriesNumber)) {
            throw new Exception('Series number is not unique.');
        }

        $seriesNumber     = new SeriesNumber($seriesNumber);
        $token            = new Token($token);
        $registerDateTime = new RegisterDateTime($registerDateTime);

        $authentication = new Authentication();
        $authentication->setSeriesNumber($seriesNumber)
                       ->setToken($token)
                       ->setRegisterDateTime($registerDateTime);

        $this->authentications[$seriesNumber] = $authentication;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Authentication child entity with the matching series number.
     *
     * @param string $seriesNumber A series number.
     *
     * @return Authentication|void An Authentication child entity instance if found.
     */
    public function findAuthenticationBySeriesNumber($seriesNumber)
    {
        if (isset($this->authentications[$seriesNumber])) {
            return $this->authentications[$seriesNumber];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes all Authentication child entities.
     */
    public function deleteAllAuthentications()
    {
        $this->authentications = [];
    }

    /**
     * Deletes the Authentication child entity with the matching series number.
     *
     * @param string $seriesNumber A series number.
     */
    public function deleteAuthenticationBySeriesNumber($seriesNumber)
    {
        if (isset($this->authentications[$seriesNumber])) {
            unset($this->authentications[$seriesNumber]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity** class:

```
namespace Model\Domain\Entity;

use \Exception;
use Model\Domain\Entity\Value\Identifier;

/**
 * Base class for all entities in the problem domain.
 *
 * @author John Doe <http://google.com>
 */
abstract class Entity
{
    /**
     * @var Identifier $identifier An identifier value object.
     */
    protected $identifier;

    /**
     * Gets the identifier.
     *
     * @return string An identifier.
     */
    public function getIdentifier()
    {
        return (string) $this->identifier;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the Identifier instance.
     *
     * @param Identifier $identifier An Identifier instance.
     *
     * @throws Exception if the identifier is already set.
     *
     * @return self The current entity.
     */
    public function setIdentifier(Identifier $identifier)
    {
        if ($this->identifier) {
            throw new Exception('Identifier is already set and therefore immutable.');
        }

        $this->identifier = $identifier;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your code look good, but since you asked specifically about comments, here are my thoughts.

**Comments**

- [commenting on getters and setters is a controversial topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028967/simple-getter-setter-comments). Your getter and setter comments generally don't add any new information. They don't really hurt either, but they can have the effect of a reader ignoring them as well as important comments. It can also have the side effect of you overlooking things that should be commented on in depth.
- `Gets the identifier.` and `An identifier.` in `getIdentifier` are not actually true. It returns a string representation of the identifier, not the identifier itself. The same is true for many of the other getter (but oddly not for `getFullName`). This should be expressed in your comments. It should probably also be noted why you are sometimes returning a string and sometimes the identifier object.
- `string  $registerDateTime A date and time of registering.`: When I have to pass a string (especially a date time string), I'd like to know how it has to be formated.

Comment: **1)** I've noticed that, but I thought it was a convention. I'm wondering, do *you* comment your getters and setters? **2)** That's correct, I will change those accordingly. Generally, value objects containing more then one value (such as a first and last name) are not casted to a string. **3)** The formatting information can be found in the `RegisterDateTime` class (will throw `InvalidArgumentException`) and in its setter comment block (of its class). But for the `addAuthentication()`, yes I'm going to add the expected format in the comment block. Thanks. :)

Comment: @KidDiamond I used to comment all getter and setters, but right now, I only do it if it adds additional information. If the name doesn't say it all (for example `setWidth`: the width of what?; `setFullName`: what's a full name? first name + last name?) and in general if there are restrictions on the parameters or side-effects or anything like that. In your case, I guess an argument could be made that your getters deserve a comment as they cast to string, and your setters because they return the `User` entity, both of which are somewhat unexpected actions.

Comment: Since I'm using value objects and not just string setters, the class itself will show what values can be retrieved from it by its getters. But I agree that if you're just using string setters, comments would be appropriate to clarify probably by using the @param tags with a description in the comment blocks. As for your last point, I think it would be nice if I added in the comments that the setters return self to allow the fluent interface implementation. Since I'm new to commenting like this I need to get used to it for a bit, to verbally express what is being done and why.